# How to include file from external local disk file system folder in JSF

Tags: jsp, pdf, jsf-2, download, facelets

I have included a JSP page into Facelets using `<ui:include>`. In JSP page I am able to get the PDF, but it displays content as plain text. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

JSP page:

```
<html>
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<body>
    <%
        response.reset();
    File file = new File(
            "D:\\TNWRD_Documents\\Knowladge_Base\\Financial_and_Administrative_powers.pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","inline;filename=Saba_PhBill.pdf");
        response.setContentLength((int)file.length());

        //OPen an input stream to the file and post the file contents thru the
        //servlet output stream to the browser
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        ServletOutputStream outs = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentLength(in.available());
        byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
        int c=0;
        try {
            while ((c = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length)) > 0) 
            {
            //System.out.println("size:"+c);
            outs.write(buf, 0, c);
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
        } finally {
            outs.flush();
            outs.close();
            in.close();
        }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

Facelets page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:my="http://example.com/jsf"
    >

    <h:form>
        <table width="100%" border="1">
        <tr></tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left" width="200px"><rich:tree id="fileTree" toggleType="ajax" var="item">
                <rich:treeModelRecursiveAdaptor
                    roots="#{fileSystemBean.sourceRoots}" nodes="#{item.directories}">
                    <rich:treeNode>
                    #{item.shortPath}
                </rich:treeNode>
                    <rich:treeModelAdaptor nodes="#{item.files}">
                        <rich:treeNode>
                            <a4j:commandLink value="#{item}"
                                action="#{TnwrdAction.downloadFile}" oncomplete="openFile();" render="fileTree"
                                immediate="true">
                                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{item}"
                                    target="#{TnwrdBean.fileName}" />

                            </a4j:commandLink>
                        </rich:treeNode>
                    </rich:treeModelAdaptor>
                </rich:treeModelRecursiveAdaptor>
                </rich:tree></td>
            <td >
            <ui:insert name="Barrage" >
            <my:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/page.jsp" />
            </ui:insert>  
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
    </h:form>

</ui:composition>
```

Comment: no solutions for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two major mistakes in this construct.

First of all, you can't include JSP files using `<ui:include>`. It can only include Facelets files. JSP files would only be treated as "plain vanilla" XML. Further, JSP is **deprecated** since JSF 2.0. You shouldn't ever think of using it. The `<ui:include>` is also the wrong tool to embed a PDF file in output. You should be using the HTML `<iframe>` or `<object>` instead.

E.g.

```html
<iframe src="/url/to/file.pdf" width="500" height="300"></iframe>
```

or, better

```html
<object data="/url/to/file.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="500" height="300">
    <a href="/url/to/file.pdf">Download file.pdf</a>
</object>
```

*(the `<a>` link is meant as graceful degradation when the browser being used doesn't support inlining `application/pdf` content in a HTML document, i.e. when it doesn't have Adobe Reader plugin installed)*

or if you happen to use PrimeFaces

```html
<p:media value="/url/to/file.pdf" width="500" height="300" />
```

Secondly, JSP is the wrong tool for the job of serving a file download. JSP is like Facelets designed as a view technology with the intent to easily produce HTML output with taglibs and EL. Basically, with your JSP approach, your PDF file is cluttered with `<html>` and `<body>` tags and therefore corrupted and not recognizable as a valid PDF file. This is by the way one of the reasons why [using *scriptlets* is a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files/3180202#3180202). It has namely completely confused you as to how stuff is supposed to work. Facelets does not support any form of *scriptlets* and hence "automatically" forces you to do things the right way. In this particular case, that is using a normal Java class for the file download job.

You should be using a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) instead. Here's a kickoff example, assuming that Servlet 3.0 and Java 7 is available:

```java
@WebServlet("/Saba_PhBill.pdf")
public class PdfServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        File file = new File("D:\\TNWRD_Documents\\Knowladge_Base\\Financial_and_Administrative_powers.pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", getServletContext().getMimeType(file.getName()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(file.length()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"Saba_PhBill.pdf\"");
        Files.copy(file.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
    }

}
```

*(you've by the way a serious typo in "Knowladge", not sure if that's further relevant to the concrete problem)*

Just replace `"/url/to/file.pdf"` by `"#{request.contextPath}/Saba_PhBill.pdf"` in above HTML examples to invoke it. In `<p:media>` the `#{request.contextPath}` is unnecessary.

Comment: But how do i call the servlet from jsf,please elaborate @BalusC

Comment: Have you missed the last paragraph of the answer?

Comment: understood but balusc iam able to add jsp in jsf and i just want to do a trial and error method . The jsp really works  fine in jsf.But only the ascii code of pdf is visible not the pdf content.  Ur method is easy but iam a newbie to jsf