# Store PDF for a limited time on app server and make it available for download

Tags: jsf, tomcat, pdf, primefaces, download

Hei there, I'm using PrimeFaces 5/JSF 2 and tomcat!

Can someone show me or give me an idea on how to store pdfs for a limited time on an application server(I'm using tomcat) and then download it (if that's what the user requests). This functionality relates to invoices so I can't use the dataExporter.

To be more specific, I pretty much implemented this but I don't feel so sure about it. One big question is... where do I store my generated files? I've browsed around and people said that it's not ok to save the files in the webApp or in the tomcat directory. What other solutiuon do I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of [`File#createTempFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) facility. The servletcontainer-managed temporary folder is available as application scoped attribute with [`ServletContext.TEMPDIR`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#TEMPDIR) as key.

```
String tempDir = (String) externalContext.getApplicationMap().get(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);
File tempPdfFile = File.createTempFile("generated-", ".pdf", tempDir);
// Write to it.
```

Then just pass the autogenerated file name around to the one responsible for serving it. E.g.

```
String tempPdfFileName = tempPdfFile.getName();
// ...
```

Finally, once the one responsible for serving it is called with the file name as parameter, for example [a simple servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207479/how-to-show-pdf-document-in-jsp-which-is-included-via-uiinclude/16215286#16215286), then just stream it as follows:

```
String tempDir = (String) getServletContext().getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);
File tempPdfFile = new File(tempDir, tempPdfFileName);
response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(tempPdfFile.length()));
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"generated.pdf\"");
Files.copy(tempPdfFile.toPath(), response.getOutputStream());
```

#### See also:

- [How to save generated file temporarily in servlet based web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31255366/java-io-filenotfoundexception-when-trying-to-save-generated-file-in-web-applicat)
- [Recommended way to save uploaded files in a servlet application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664579/recommended-way-to-save-uploaded-files-in-a-servlet-application)

Comment: Just an observation, the line:
`String tempDir = (String) getServletContext().getAttribute(ServletContext.TEMPDIR);`
gives ClassCastException because it returns a File not a String.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but if my understanding is good:

First if you want to store the PDF for a limited time you can create a job that clean you PDFs every day or week or whatever you need.

For the download side, you can use `<p:fileDownload>` (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/file/download.xhtml) to download any file from the application server.